# Linux GVim via SSH -X does not copy paste on selection

Tags: linux, ssh, gvim, copy-paste

I'm using SSH (with -X specified) from a Ubuntu box to a RHEL4 box and running GVim.  It opens as expected in my local X, but the copy and paste via select doesn't work.  I cannot select text in GVim and paste in  a local window, nor can I select text from a local window and paste in GVim.  This works, however, when I SSH (with -X specified) to a different RHEL4 box.

Is there something I need to install on the remote machine?

I am running Parcellite 0.9.2 on the local box, but closing it doesn't make the problem go away, and it is not interfering with the other box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that vim on the remote was not compiled with GTK.  This happened because the necessary package was not present on the remote box.

To fix it, log on to the remote machine and:

1. Install gtk2-devel,
2. re-configure, re-make, & re-install vim

A co-worker figured this out eventually.